# Comparing two .txt files showing common words or phrases

Tags: python, file, file-io, python-3.x

I am trying to compare two .txt files and find out every common word in the two (ignoring case sensitivity. If someone could point me towards the right direction that would be helpful. (I don't have any python writing experience, just editing a few scripts)

Comment: @bernie: the innocent "or phrases" at the end of the question makes it a slightly more complex problem.

Comment: Well spotted. I agree that also searching for phrases makes this a more complex problem. How much more complex depends on how many edge-cases the OP wishes to accommodate.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you list containing common words from two files. Output format is list.

```
with open('a','r') as f, open('b','r') as g:
  l=f.readlines()
  l1=g.readlines()
  print list(set(l)&set(l1))
```